# what is "the next time in this round" in Ascension?

Tags: ascension

I have just started playing Ascension Storm of Souls. Since i have no previous experience from other card games like this, i find the description of some of the rules to be not quite as clear and precise as i would have liked. Which, to some extent, might be explained by the fact that English is not my mother tounge. Anyways..

After playing a about ten games, i think that most of my questions have been worked out. But one.

Many of the cards have effects that are worded like:
Example 1 - "Gain 2 runes. The next time you acquire a Hero this turn, you may put it on top of your deck." or 
Example 2 - "Gain 1 rune. You pay 1 rune less the next time you acquire a Hero this turn." or 
Example 3 -"You may destroy this to pay 2 runes less the next time you acquire a Mechana Construct this turn."

How should "the next time you do X in this turn" be understood? In example 1 do i get the effect for the second Hero i acquire during that turn?

If my reading comprehension dosen't fail me completely, that's what i think it says. But, if so, then i almost never get to use those effects, because i rarely acquire more than one hero per turn. Which makes me believe that I just maybe is reading it wrong.. and that the effects are supposed to be read when i draw them from the card and put them out on the table in front of me. Which would mean that "the next time you acquire a Hero/destroy a construct etc" is actually the first time i acquire/destroy something, because "next" i just refering to a later time in the same round...

Śo, which is it?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you asking if those cards have that effect the first time you gain them, or when you play them from your hand?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you buy the card in Example 1, you don't get 2 runes. Why would you think that "The next time you..." is applied?

All of these things happen when you **play** the cards, not when you buy them.

Many times, the order in which you play cards from your hand does not matter. Bt if you are planning to buy two cards in a turn after playing the card from Example 1, make sure the one that you buy first is the one that you want to go on top of your deck.

Comment: So when i play a card that says "the next time you acquire a hero this turn" it could also be read "the first time you acquire a hero this turn"?

Comment: @Erik: no. Technically, you could play that card **after** already having acquired a hero, so any subsequent acquisitions would not be "the first" of the turn. Contrast this with **Dominion**, wherein the Buy Phase is necessarily after the Action Phase.

Comment: I can see the confusion. No, "Next" in this context does NOT imply that it's already happened once before. The next time might be the very first time. Or it might be the second time, if you already did it once before playing the card with the "next time" effect.

Compare to MTG. Some cards say "the next time damage would be dealt..."

Comment: @Gen: right. I guess they could read "the next time, **after you play this card**, that ...". But that is ugly!